# How to make address1 field and zip code non required with Address Field module

Tags: 7, location, entities

I'm using [Address Field](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module

I want to make it a required field but only the Country and City values. I want to leave the zip code and Address as optional. I don't find a way to configure it like this. Is it possible?

To provide more info, I am using Geocoder to fill a Geofield field. I want it to be able to geolocate with City and Country if only that are provided if also zip code and address are provided use them too.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if I make the whole Address field non-required works as I want to, but I would like to make Country and City required, another way to look at the problem.

Comment: Check out this issue: [Configurable non-empty value conditions](https://drupal.org/node/1263316). Posted on August 29, 2011 and still not even assigned to anyone. Good luck with getting an answer here...

Comment: @Mołot yeah it looks like its been a problem for some years now...I think I will let it be for now and work in other issues and go back in the refining stage of the site. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I was helping you with it before you knew you need it :P reviewing patches since 2012. Sorry for a bitter tone of my first comment, but as you may tell, I'm tired with it.

Comment: The fact that it still hasn't reached a working consensus (there are many intermediate patches) shows there's still work to be done. I'm slowly working my way through these issues, but ultimately there were bigger issues to tackle first.

Also, form altering will work just fine even without a configuration for it.

Comment: @RyanSzrama Thanks for your work. It is not an urgent matter so I can get along with letting all fields as optional. Is there anyway to keep up to date with the development of the module?

Comment: No worries - unfortunately I don't have a better development log than the issue queue itself. You can track the commits to get the clearest picture of what's going in (I always reference the issue number) or just keep an eye on updates to the issue queue. I really want to get configurable non-empty conditions, but I just had to go ahead and pull the trigger on a beta5 until I can wade through the patches and make it work with the addressfield element type patch.

Comment: @garnav, as a workaround you can alter the form having address field in it, and using [#after_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#after_build) make necessary changes to make field required/non-required. Not sure, but you try [Address Empty](https://www.drupal.org/project/address_empty) Module, if it works in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I would use form_alter to hook into the form, identify the form element and unset or make required FALSE

eg:

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

  if($form_id == 'xyz'){
   $form['zipcode']['#required'] = FALSE;
   $form['address']['#required'] = FALSE;
  }

}
```